# Sidebar com efeito accordion

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-3, menu

Dada uma `sidebar`, como faço para obter o efeito de um *accordion*?

Atualmente, a minha `sidebar` funciona quase perfeitamente. Isso quer dizer que, ao clicar em menus que possuem submenus, eles são expandidos. Eu só não estou conseguindo fazer com que um menu expansível recolha (*collapse*) quando outro menu (também expansível) for selecionado.

Segue meu código da sidebar:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav side-nav">
    <li>
      <a href="javascript:;" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#acc-dashboard"><i class="fa fa-window-restore sb-icon text-center"></i><span class="sb-span">Dashboards</span>
      <i class="fa fa-fw fa-angle-right pull-right"></i></a>
      <ul id="acc-dashboard" class="collapse">
        <li class="nav-item-1">
          <a href="#"><span class="sb-span">Entregas</span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#"><span class="sb-span">Mesas</span></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="javascript:;" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#acc-financeiro"><i class="fa fa-dollar sb-icon text-center"></i><span class="sb-span">Financeiro</span>
      <i class="fa fa-fw fa-angle-right pull-right"></i></a>
      <ul id="acc-financeiro" class="collapse">
        <li>
          <a href="#"><span class="sb-span">Contas a receber</span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#"><span class="sb-span">Contas a pagar</span></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

> Visualizar o exemplo acima em "Página toda".

Comment: Você já tentou utilizar o `dropdown`?

Comment: Estou dando uma olhada na documentação do w3c. Acredito que a solução para o que eu preciso está no data-parent. Mas, por enquanto, nada ainda.

Answer (score 1):

Veja um exemplo utilizando o componente [`dropdown`](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns) do Bootstrap:

> Ao clicar em **Executar**, visualize em **Página toda**, à direita do botão Executar.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav side-nav">
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <i class="fa fa-window-restore sb-icon text-center"></i>
        <span class="sb-span">Dashboards</span>
        <i class="fa fa-fw fa-angle-right pull-right"></i>
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li class="nav-item-1">
          <a href="#"><span class="sb-span">Entregas</span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#"><span class="sb-span">Mesas</span></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <i class="fa fa-dollar sb-icon text-center"></i>
        <span class="sb-span">Financeiro</span>
        <i class="fa fa-fw fa-angle-right pull-right"></i>
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li>
          <a href="#"><span class="sb-span">Contas a receber</span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#"><span class="sb-span">Contas a pagar</span></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Consiste em basicamente você adicionar a classe `dropdown` ao elemento pai do elemento que abrirá o menu. No seu caso, como serão os elementos `a` os responsáveis, adicione a classe `dropdown` aos elementos `li`. Aos elementos `a` adicione o atributo `data-toggle="dropdown"` e os elementos `ul` que representam os submenus adicione a classe `dropdown-menu`. Desta forma o comportamento do menu será exatamente o que você deseja. Acredito que o comportamento padrão do `accordion` é manter os itens abertos mesmo quando outros são também abertos e não seria muito recomendado alterar este comportamento, pois o código acaba ficando inconsistente. Acredito que o `dropdown` faz bem o que você precisa.

Answer (score 0):

Encontrei a solução. Tive que fazer algumas modificações e utilizar a classe `panel` nas tags `li` da minha `sidebar`.

Ficou basicamente assim:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
  <ul id="accordion1" class="nav navbar-nav side-nav">
    <li class="panel">
      <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#acc-dashboard">
        <i class="fa fa-window-restore sb-icon text-center"></i><span class="sb-span">Dashboards</span>
        <i class="fa fa-fw fa-angle-right pull-right"></i></a>
      <ul id="acc-dashboard" class="collapse">
        <li class="nav-item-1">
          <a href="#"><span class="sb-span">Entregas</span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#"><span class="sb-span">Mesas</span></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="panel">
      <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#acc-financeiro">
        <i class="fa fa-dollar sb-icon text-center"></i><span class="sb-span">Financeiro</span>
        <i class="fa fa-fw fa-angle-right pull-right"></i></a>
      <ul id="acc-financeiro" class="collapse">
        <li>
          <a href="#"><span class="sb-span">Contas a receber</span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#"><span class="sb-span">Contas a pagar</span></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Pode funcionar, mas tome cuidado com o que eu escrevi na minha resposta. Alterar o comportamento padrão de algo geralmente não é muito indicado. Você pode saber como o código funciona hoje, mas daqui alguns meses, quando precisar dar manutenção do projeto, você poderá não lembrar que alterou o comportamento do `accordion` e ficar confuso. Minha dica: somente o faça se tiver absoluta consciência do que está fazendo.